# Multiline anonymous function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, lambda, anonymous-function

Is it possible to create multiline anonymous function in Matlab?

There are no appropriate examples [in documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html), but also no direct denials. In web discussions I found some derisions of askers as if it silly wish. Nowadays, when most languages introducing lambda expressions with multiline capability this looks strange.

Comment: Multi-line: Yes. Use the ellipsis: `...` to signalize a continued line. Multi-expressions: No.

Comment: From the doc: anonymous functions "can contain only a single executable statement"

Comment: 'pc = @(x) {plot(x);colorbar}', then just call pc(1:10)

Answer (score 6):

No, unfortunately this is not possible.